# How to get radiobutton value in angular 2?

Tags: angular, radio-button, pug, angular2-ngmodel

I am working a project where i need to bind 3 radio buttons per row in table. I am binding this table but somehow its not happening. I am sharing my code what i have done.

```
table.table
    thead
        tr
            th
                | To
            th
                | Cc
            th
                | Bcc
            th
                | First Name
            th
                | Last Name
            th
                | Phone
            th
                | Email
        tbody
            tr(*ngFor = "let contact of contacts| values")
                td
                    input(type="radio" , [(ngModel)]="contact.value.option", [name]="contact.key", value="to")
                td
                    input(type="radio" , [(ngModel)]="contact.value.option", [name]="contact.key", value="cc")
                td
                    input(type="radio" , [(ngModel)]="contact.value.option", [name]="contact.key", value="bcc")
                td
                    | {{contact.value.fName}}
                td
                    | {{contact.value.lName}}
                td
                    | {{contact.value.phone}}
                td
                    | {{contact.value.email}}
```

I have tried this [How to bind to radio buttons in angular2 beta 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35653175/how-to-bind-to-radio-buttons-in-angular2-beta-6) but its not working.

**EDIT** As asked in comment. I have created one [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Dx5bsl6DQe70ShXSuYIE?p=preview).

**PS**  This code is in `pug`(Jade).

Comment: Radio buttons were improved a lot in recent versions. I'd suggest you upgrade to RC.4 and the new forms module.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thank you for your response. All you are saying is to use formConrol?

Comment: You can just use `ngModel` but it's handled (provided) by the forms module and how `ngModel` works with `<input type="radio">` has changed and was simplified quite a bit.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i tried that . but not getting anything

Comment: Please create a Plunker that allows to reproduce. Plunker provides a nice Angular2 TS template using the `New` button in the editor.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i have added plunkr. I know which is not working. I am bindin data from firebase but as in plunkr i have used static data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you upgrade to RC.4 and the new forms module your code works without change.

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms} from '@angular/forms';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  disableDeprecatedForms(),
  provideForms()
]);
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/HibXak2C6PLTMIvaXuY2?p=preview)

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer. But as i am adding it in the `main.ts`  Soon that component is not getting hanged.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand "Soon that component is not getting hanged.". Are you importing forms stuff from `@angular/common` anywhere in your app? You need to migrate all your forms stuff to the new form if you want to use what I suggested in my answer.

Comment: Actually what i am saying is after i tried this in my `main.ts`. My page starts hanging too much. I cant do anything in that page. Rest of the components are working very fine.

Comment: If you can extract that in Plunker (as small as possible) that would be great. Otherwise it's hard to guess.

Comment: I have created plunkr but in plunkr its working everything good. In my machine specifically this page gets hanged. http://plnkr.co/edit/Y0vWjdX0EZu6UhBekH5O?p=preview 
PS: Click on "TO". It will show you the list.

Comment: Can you investigate in devtools what's going on? (profiler, memory usage, ...)

Comment: But if i remove `[(ngModel)]` or the two references from `main.ts` it works fine. Still that be an issue of something else?

Comment: If it's working in the Plunker I'd say it's caused by something else.

Comment: i think the same way. still wondering what will be the issue. :(

Comment: Got the solution. It was the pipe that i have used with it. Thank you once again :)

Comment: @RonakBhatt Glad to hear :) thanks for the feedback.