# Using Radio buttons in angular2 Control Array

Tags: angular

Hello I have a control array which consists of control group, and the looping the control array in the template to create radio buttons. I am able to select all the radio buttons eventhough they belong to the different control group and has different name for them...I have made a plunker demo here http://plnkr.co/edit/jTMZUCj5JVFazlZo7e4W?p=preview (the plunker demo is in beta 9) ... When i remove the [ngFormControl] it works perfectly...
can somebody please tell me the correct way to implement that?

```ts
  ArrayData=['abhi','rahul'];

ArrayControl=new ControlArray([]);

constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {  

this.ArrayControl=new ControlArray([]);

for(var i=0;i<this.ArrayData.length;i++){
  let myForm = fb.group({
  'Male':  ['', Validators.required]  ,
  'Female':  ['', Validators.required]
}); 

  this.ArrayControl.push(myForm);
}

}
```

This is how i am creating the control array...

```ts
        <div *ngFor="#control of ArrayControl.controls;#i=index">
      <input type="radio" name="{{i}}" value="male" [ngFormControl]="control.controls['Male']"> Male<br>
      <input type="radio" name="{{i}}" value="female" [ngFormControl]="control.controls['Female']"> Female<br>
      <hr>
    </div>
```

In this way i am looping the template...
Can somebody please tell me where i am doing wrong?

Comment: Does it need to be the old forms module or is the new forms module fine as well?

Comment: New Forms module is fine for me...

Comment: @GunterZochbauer does the above requirement works fine if i implement them using new forms(RC-4)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**update**

Not applicable to the final Angular 2 release.

**original**

This might be what you're looking for:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES],    
  template: `
<div class="ui raised segment"> 
  <h3>Select Gender</h3>
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <div formArrayName="arr">
      <div *ngFor="let item of arrayData; let i=index">
        <div>{{item}}</div>
        <input type="radio" [formControlName]="i" value="male"> Male<br>
        <input type="radio" [formControlName]="i" value="female"> Female<br>
        <hr>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div>data: {{form.value | json}}</div>
</div>  

  `
})
export class AppComponent { 
  arrayData=['abhi','rahul'];

  //gender = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
  arr = new FormArray([]);

  constructor() {  
    this.form=new FormGroup({ 'arr': this.arr });
    console.log(this.form);
    for(var i=0; i < this.arrayData.length; i++){
      this.arr.push(new FormControl('', [Validators.required]));
    } 
  }
}
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/1ezNZku6SxU6loknnZjx?p=preview)

Comment: Where's the binding? Adding radio buttons has always worked. It's kind of an odd thing to use an index (i) as the "name" of a radio button property and where would use set the gender based on existing data? You're setting it to a completely invalid value and forcing the user to click something''

Comment: @RickO'Shea There was a new forms module introduced since and wrote this answer. Radio buttons weren't supported well before that. I haven't used radio buttons since a long time and don't know by heart how to use them. There should be several other answers out that demonstrate it.